# How do holding patterns work?

Tags: air-traffic-control, instrument-flight-rules, autopilot, holding

How does a pilot follow a holding pattern? Do pilots have to manually change heading and altitude (through the autopilot) each time they are making a turn? Or is it something the Flight Management Computer (FMC) can handle?

Comment: You might need to improve your question. You added `air-traffic-control` tag in your question but the question body has nothing to do with ATC. Also "How do holding patterns work?" is a very broad title that will call for a variety of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking the Flight Management Computer supports holding patterns. The pilot inputs the holding fix (usually a NDB/VOR), the direction of the hold (Left/Right), the inbound course, and the time/distance that one holding leg shall take to execute. These information can be found on aeronautical charts, as IFR holding patterns are published for each airport. As far as I know pilots are also trained to fly holding patterns manually, but you can understand that flying the pattern manually is not as precise as flying the pattern via the autopilot.